# different behavior when run in nohup mode (linux shell)

Tags: linux, shell, nohup

I try to do string replacement in linux shell,

```
str=2011/10/10
echo "$str"
a=${str//\//\_}
echo $a
```

It can execute when I invoke command : ./test.sh
But if I run it in nohup mode, using command : nohup ./test.sh &

It says that 
./test.sh: 8: Bad substitution

What's wrong here ?

Thanks

Comment: Works fine here (bash 4.2.10(2) and nohup 8.14).

Comment: Your script only has 4 lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you have no `#!/bin/bash` at the top of your script, the 'nohup' command is using /bin/sh and your system's /bin/sh isn't BASH. Your first and third lines where you assign 'str' and 'a' are not correct Bourne syntax.

Since you likely want to use BASH and not a shell that uses strict Bourne syntax, you should add a #! line at the top of your script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
str=2011/10/10
echo "$str"
a=${str//\//\_}
echo $a
```

Comment: The issue I had was that I had extra space, and after removing it worked: "# !/bin/bash" -> "#!/bin/bash"